# How can i use Cells.EntireColumn.Autofit in all Sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub teste()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does this already or is there an error? You could restrict it to the used range and you shouldn't activate each worksheet i.e. inside the loop use the single line `ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit` to make it more efficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.